# Java Reusing interface methods

Tags: java, interface, functional-programming, expression

This is the interface I'm using:

```
interface Command {
    void run(int a, int b, int c);
    void run(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);
}

void add(Command c){

}
```

this is execution: (using the first run method)

```
    add((a, b, c) -> System.out.println(""));
```

The error i get on the execution is:

```
    The target type of this expression must be a functional interface
```

And this only goes away when i comment out the second run method.

I want to be able to execute the same interface using both run methods, and not have to create a new interface just to execute with method 2.

How?

Comment: Say I'm implementing your `add` method. You call it with `add((a, b, c) -> System.out.println(""));`. What do you expect to happen if, in the implementation of `add`, I call `c.add(1,2,3,4,5);`? Why do you expect that?

Answer (score 1):

A [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) by design is allowed to have just one method so what you are trying to do can't be done directly, it's clear why: allowing to implement a functional interface with a lambda must create an object which is valid for its declaration, if it has two methods you cant implement them both with a single lambda.

A workaround could be to use variadic arguments, eg:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Command {
 void run(int... args); 
}

add(args -> { int z = args[0] + args[1] + args[2]; });
```

Comment: I guess that method works fine, but with that i would have to make an argument an instance of something to call a method:

        ((Automobile)args[0]).getInCar()

is there a way this can be done better?